# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment in wavfileread

Tags: python, wav

I used scipy.io's wavfile to read the wav file which has 3 channels.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate,data_origin = wavfile.read('file1.wav')
```

However I received `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`

May I know how can I solve this issue?
Is it related to the audio file issue?
Thank you.

Comment: That code didn't produce that error.  I suggest including the full traceback in your question, and looking at the traceback yourself to see what part of your code is actually responsible for that exception.

Comment: Hello Samwise,  
The error shows in this line 
 ```samplerate,data_origin = wavfile.read('file1.wav')

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 707, in read
    return fs, data

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment```

Comment: That error is coming out of `scipy`, maybe they have some broken error handling if the file can't be read?  Have you double-checked that you have the file's path correct (maybe try specifying it as an absolute path if you aren't sure) and that it's a valid WAV file?

Comment: yes I checked the file path is correct. 
I also tried using librosa.load() to read the wav file. Actually, the wav file has 3 channels and in librosa.load(), it gives only  1 channel data. 
Moreover I also tried using ```obj = wave.open('file1.wav','r')```, I got 
```
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\wave.py", line 155, in initfp
    raise Error('fmt chunk and/or data chunk missing')

Error: fmt chunk and/or data chunk missing```

Comment: That sounds like something is wrong with the file...

Comment: But I am curious if the file has issue, why it can open with audacity ?

Comment: Probably because `scipy` has more specific requirements.  The fact that it produces an `UnboundLocalError` instead of a better error letting you know *what* those requirements are reflects very poorly on `scipy`; I'd personally see that as a red flag and try to find an alternative library.